# How to override nightwatch js xml report names with timestamp?

Tags: javascript, testing, reporting, nightwatch.js, jsreport

I want to append my nightwatch js xml report files with timestamp of the execution time. How can I do that ? Can anyone please help?

Comment: It looks like junit.xml.ejs includes a time & timestamp for each test.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes I am using the latest version but still it is not generating reports with timestamp. I have tried various option in the nightwatch.conf.js file in order to override it, but that didn't work either